# Error 1071: Cannot convert a map to an Integer

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I have an HBase table 'events' and I am trying to read the data from it using Apache Pig.

When I run the following I get an **'Error 1071: Cannot convert a map to an Integer'**

```
events = LOAD 'hbase://events' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf1:*, '-loadKey true') as (eventid:int,eventtype:int,productid:int,timestamp:long,userid:int,version:int);
```

If I run the following I am able to get the data:

```
events = LOAD 'hbase://events' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf1:eventtype cf1:productid cf1:timestamp cf1:userid cf1:version, '-loadKey true') as (eventid:int,eventtype:int,productid:int,timestamp:long,userid:int,version:int);
```

Which returns all the data from the HBase table:

- (1, 1, 202, 1237464302, 4, 5)
- (2, 1, 212, 1254136012, 4, 5)
- (3, 1, 230, 1259212134, 4, 5)
- (4, 1, 202, 1308435412, 4, 5)

I've tried several things to try getting the data using 'cf1:*', but I can't seem to get it to work although all the examples I've seen show that it's possible. Anyone can explain better how to not specify all the columns and maybe point me in the right direction?